# reference another dropdown value from js method call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass in values from another dropdown (ddlColor) and pass it's selected id and text value into the event method for ddlEngine

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEngine" runat="server" onchange="GetSearchResults(ddlColor.value, ddlColor.text, this.options[selectedIndex].text);" />
```

I guess I can't reference the ddlColor like this, something is not right in my syntax and I can't see what.

Here is my attempt:

this is defined globally at the top of my page just after the js tag:

```
var ddlColor = document.getElementById('<%=ddlColor.ClientID %>');

var colorid_dropdown = ddlColor.options[ddlColor.selectedIndex].value;
var colorname_dropdown = ddlColor.options[ddlColor.selectedIndex].text;
```

then in teh onchange of my dropdown I tried to append it to the call:

```
onchange="GetSearchResults("' + colorid_dropdown + ", " + "'colorname_dropdown + '" + ", this.options[selectedIndex].text);"
```

Comment: I need to access it by getelementbyid but how would I do this out of scope of the GetSearchResults method call in this dropdown?  Append the id with string appends to form the method call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `out of scope of the GetSearchResults method`.  You should be able to use the method I described below in any js function if ddlColor is an asp.net control on your page.  There shouldn't be any issues with stuff being out of scope.

Comment: Are you placing `ddlColor` into a js variable like you did with `ddlCar`?

Comment: Sorry yea I was in a hurry and messed up the post.  Thanks for correcting the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ClientID property of the DropDownList:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlColor.ClientID %>');
```

UPDATE:

In your updated code sample you don't appear to be placing `ddlColor` into a JS variable like you did with `ddlCar`.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: Yea I know how to do that but to append the method call string in my web control is what I'm having trouble with...concatenating.

Comment: So is `GetSearchResults` a javascript method?

Answer (score 0):

Define this as global, at the top of the page

```
var ddlColor = document.getElementById('<%=ddlColor.ClientID %>');
```

And this as your `ddlEngine` dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEngine" runat="server" onchange="GetSearchResults(ddlColor.value, ddlColor.options[ddlColor.selectedIndex].text, this.options[selectedIndex].text);"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: wait so I don't need to append strings to get out of literal text to append variable values here?

Comment: No, all text that is going in the `onchange` attribute is going to be treated as one Javascript block. And your variables are Javascript variables, so you're ok.

Comment: ok good to know...I'm too acquainted with stupid asp.net server-side includes....